# Using google's protobuf in python without installing it

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

It seems to me that when I'm using protobuf in python I need to install it first so that I also have setuptools installed. To me it seems like this is severly limiting portability as I would have to install protobuf on every machine on which I want to use any kind of python code using protobuf.

So my question is: Is there a way to package protobuf for python in such a way, that it can be distributed with the python code using it?

Any info on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package contains an experimental C++ extension, and the setup file generates Python files, but with the extension disabled by default, you should be able to include the `setup.py build` result with your script just fine.

Note that the Python package still needs the command-line tool to be installed. The tool is used to generate some Python for you.

Once that is available, run:

```
cd python
python setup.py build
```

and copy the `build/lib/google` directory to your script distribution, it needs to be on your `sys.path` to be importable.

Alternatively, use `setup.py bdist --formats=zip` and add the path to the resulting zipfile (located in `dist/protobuf-<version>.<platform>-<architecture>.zip`) to your `sys.path`. Renaming it should be fine.

Do note that the package uses a namespace, and thus the `pkg_resources` module needs to be available as well. It is only used to declare the `google` namespace in `google/__init__.py`.

Comment: I tried this put could not figure out how. Could you give me some pointers as to what to do with the zip and egg file please. Just putting them on the PythonPath doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @Cornelius: I was in the process of updating; a `build` is enough, really.

Comment: Ah, yes, I that was my first guess but if I do this I get the error message: "ImportError: No module named pkg_resources". Supposedly because I haven't got setuptools installed. Is this what you mean by command-line tool?

Comment: @Cornelius: No, `pkg_resources` is part of the setuptools distribution yes. I guess you'd have to include that *too* in your packaging. Why not just use the `setuptools` infrastructure instead and have `pip` or `easy_install` handle installation and dependencies for you?

Comment: Yes, you have to add the pkg_resources.py to you path as well for this to work. I found this answer also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252910/how-to-include-and-use-eggs-pkg-resources-within-a-project-directory-targeting. Could you update your answer please and then I'll check it as the correct one. Thanks for your help.